# Load credential from environment varaible

Tags: node.js, fortify

I want to call some Fortify APIs using nodejs
But for that i need to give administrator credentials
How can i load the credentials from my environment variable?
Example:-

```
SSCURL = xyz
SSCUSERNAME=changeme
SSCPASSWORD=changeme
```

Comment: You can check here how to load env file variables https://github.com/Abdurraheem/REST-API-JWTWEB-TOKEN or you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Answer (score 2):

There is a system variable `process.env`, first example in node.js:

```
const SSCURL = process.env.SSCURL;
const SSCURSERNAME = porcess.env.SSCURSERNAME;
const SSCPASSWORD = process.env.SCCPASSWORD;
```

You can use this as normal constant afterwards...